# Am I being spied on my messenger?

Tags: monitoring, user-management

OK. Let's make it clear: I am in a corporate network, and I have suspicions on being spyed. Don´t problem with that, not my PC, not my network. It´s fine.

So, just curious: How I can know if they are spying on my **messenger conversations**?

**Edit**: Can I find any clues **on my computer** of being spied on messenger?

Comment: This really isn't a computer hardware/software program

Comment: @KronoS: I have edited my question.

Comment: It's still not really a good question...

Comment: Added to my answer.

Comment: @Kronos: You first said it was not about software/hardware. I agree, it was bad redacted. Why is it not a good question now? Not useful? subjective or argumentative? superficial?

Comment: Voting to close. This doesn't relate to professional systems administration, etc.

Comment: If you are on a corporate network it's not called being spied on, it's just part of your companies policy. Deal with it. Also if you are on a corporate network assume that everything you do is being recorded by a server someplace in the company.

Comment: @Tim Meers: You don´t read my question... I wrote: It´s fine, just curiosity. I am not asking about cheat, avoid, bypass my company policies... not asking how to react if being spyed... I just ask: Is there a way to KNOW? Thanks.

Comment: @Robert Moir: the question was migrated here...

Comment: Edgar, yes it was. I still don't think it belongs here.

Comment: @Tim Meers: if you are on a corporate network it's still called being spied on, even if it is mentioned explicitly in the corporate policy. A sane policy would just prohibit instant messaging at work for personal use, if the employer considers this a problem.

Comment: @RobertM I guess it got migrated because someone assumed it would involve analyzing network traffic. I suppose it should be on SuperUser, but it seems people don't mind answering the question (and I see it was migrated away from SuperUser, strange).

Comment: @Mark C: I agree. I post it on superuser as a valid question of a user, not network administrator. Anyway, thanks for all the answers and comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... if you network is secure and your PC is secure, where are you insinuating that they would manipulate your packets? The internet? If that is true, the person probably knows what they are doing and they do a simple manipulation of the pack and send it to you and act as a gateway. The only way you can prevent it is using an encrypted connection, preferably an encryption that uses a pre-shared key.

**EDIT**: No you can't.

Comment: @David: I don´t want to prevent it (corporate network, not my network). Just wondering if someone is actually spying me. Thanks.

Comment: @David: Thats the type of answer I was looking for: no advices, just yes or not, and a possible explanation, if possible. Thanks.

Comment: @Edgar I explained before I said "No." If you understand gateways and manipulation of packets, you would understand the answer more in depth. Do research on packet manipulation packet sniffing, and the importance of data encrytpopn if you would like to learn more about it.

Answer (score 9):

- Ask "them"
- Ask HR
- Read company policy
- Seed false information and see if it is acted upon.
- Act as if everything you type is read by your boss, the CIO and your mom.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick: I have edited my question to reflect my interest. Repeat: I don´t have any problem with this, just geek curiosity.

Comment: There's no way to be sure your Messenger conversations are not monitored. They can be monitored in transit without touching your PC or leaving any traces there. This is really more of a social issue than a technical one.

Comment: Yes, you're being watched.  No, there's nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 3):

> I can find any clues on my computer of being spied on messenger?

**No.**

Comment: Says who? it can be his computer is being spied on by the company

Comment: .... and you know he's being spied upon HOW ? His question is NOT whether he **can** be spied upon, it's whether he can **find out** if he's being spied upon. @TomTom

Comment: You dont. Not without admin access (which a normal user in a company does not have). Sky kits are made to not be detected by the normal user.

Answer (score 1):

Oh Cmon

If anyone has ever played with NTOP you can clearly see which IP's/People are using which protocol..

To take it a step further ( havent done this is a while )
Using a packet sniffer and a mirrored port on a core switch..
you can just listen to all the traffic..

Whereby you can actually read MSN messages etc etc.. (however it might be encrypted recently)

The art of watching is not tampering with your computer..
Its just listening... and surveying..

Comment: +1 - IIRC Smoothwall has a feature that displays MSN conversions in real time as they pass through the firewall

Answer (score 0):

I use XMPP (Jabber*) as my IM, and the client I use (Gajim*) warns me if the SSL certificate on the server is not what it was expecting. If you checked first at home then at work, you could see if the certificates are the same or not. If they are not the same, then they are possibly spying on you with a man-in-the-middle attack. If they are the same, then it is not possible for them to read your encrypted conversations.

* This might be possible with other clients or protocols, I just know for sure with these ones as that's what I use.

Answer (score 0):

What IM are you using? If MSN not encrypted, the messages are easily spied. Hacker is able to spy messages anywhere on your message route. Perhaps this post makes you understand why: http://blog.colasoft.com/how-to-monitor-instant-message-activity-with-capsa/